# Keras model.fit console output displays wrong number of batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, model

I want to train my model using the whole training data simultaneously, i.e. without using batches. However, when I fit the model, the output in the console displays `(25/25)` which indicates (to my knowledge) the use of 25 batches.
`X_train` is (3967, 7), `y_train` is (3967, 3), `X_test` is (793, 7) and
`y_test` is (793, 3)

```
model.fit(X_train,
          y_train,
          epochs=1000,
          batch_size=X_train.shape[0],
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[callback],
          validation_steps=1,
          steps_per_epoch=1,
          verbose=0,
 )

25/25 [==============================] - 0s 680us/step - loss: 0.0021 - mean_squared_error: 1.8719e-04 - root_mean_squared_error: 0.0137 - mean_absolute_error: 0.0077
```

I also tried to fit the model without using the parameters `validation_steps=1` and `steps_per_epoch=1` (ignoring them and sticking to the default value) which didn't solve the issue.

I use tensorflow 2.3.0

Comment: I don't think the terminal is showing an incorrect value, but maybe the batch size you are using is not correct, for example if x_train and y_train are tf datasets, then they have their own batch sizes.

Comment: Thanks, but x_train and y_train are numpy arrays. I just use their length as batch size to pass the full  training set

Comment: Validation steps and steps per epoch are only used with generators or tf datasets. Does the number of batches change with the batch size?

Comment: No it does not change, but regardless of whether I use validation steps and steps per epoch

Comment: I am talking about batch size, forget about steps completely. Maybe put a reproducible example in your question.